# Day difference within various periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
    id int,
    year float
);

INSERT INTO tab1 (id, year)
VALUES 
  (1, '2015'),
       (1, '2016'),
       (1, '2017'),
       (1, '2018'),
       (1, '2019'),
       (1, '2020'),
       (1, '2021'),
      (3, '2014'),   
       (3, '2015'),
       (3, '2016'),
       (3, '2017'),
       (3, '2018'),
       (3, '2019'),
       (3, '2020')

  
CREATE TABLE tab2 (
    id int,
    startdate date,
    enddate date
);

INSERT INTO tab2 (id, startdate, enddate)
VALUES 
  (1,'2015-03-01', '2020-12-31'),
       (1,'2021-01-01', '2021-04-20'),
  (3, '2014-03-01', '2019-08-09'),
       (3, '2019-08-12', '2020-01-31')
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7ZnZn7Yj) for data and query.

An ID can have multiple contracts without gaps in between (ID 1) or with gaps in between (ID 3).

Here is the table with the wrong calculation in bold:

| id | year | startdate | enddate | drop_out | diff_smallest_startdate_drop_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2016 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2017 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2018 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2019 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2020 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 3 | 2014 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2015 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2016 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2017 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2018 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2019 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2020 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 | **2162** |

I tried to calculate the day difference between the `startdate` and the `drop_out` date.

The problem is that I took the smallest `startdate` for calculation, but because ID3 has two times of `drop_out` i need to take the next `startdate` after the first `drop_out` date for calculation and i dont know how.

Here is what I expect:

| id | year | startdate | enddate | drop_out | diff_smallest_startdate_drop_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2016 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2017 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2018 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2019 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2020 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 3 | 2014 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2015 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2016 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2017 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2018 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2019 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2020 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 | 173 |

Comment: how join two table ?when i join two table based on id (return 26 but you have 15 rows)?if next year row=current row must insert to drop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point

Comment: when  i join how two table (i get 26 rows) https://dbfiddle.uk/SiIb-qXH

Comment: I added another prerequisite to my `ON` clause using `AND`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/aDIpmtni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
      a.id
     ,a.year
     ,a.startdate
     ,a.enddate
      ,drop_out,DATEDIFF(day,start_drop,drop_out) as 
      diff_smallest_startdate_drop_out

from (
SELECT t.id,t.year,tab2.startdate,tab2.enddate,
case when 
lead(t.year,1,0) over(partition by t.id order by t.id)=t.year +1
then null else tab2.enddate end
as drop_out
,lag(tab2.startdate) over(partition by t.id order by t.id)start_drop


FROM 
  tab1  t
JOIN tab2 ON t.id = tab2.id 
AND YEAR(tab2.startdate) <= YEAR(CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(t.year AS INT) - 1900, '19000101') AS DATE)) 
AND YEAR(tab2.enddate) >= YEAR(CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(t.year AS INT) - 1900, '19000101') AS DATE))

)a
```

dbfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/yO_9VrnB

Comment: Thank you very much. In this case it works perfect. But when I add multiple drop outs within an ID the day difference calculation is wrong.

Comment: Can you send example data?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/qulNYufG - I also added my query, because it notes if someone gets another contract without a gap.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. In this query, it checks the current year with the previous year, if the year hasn't changed, it considers it as a gap and calculates it.
Row=16 >current Year=2015 and Pervious year =2015 ,current Year<>Pervious year+1

Comment: when you take a look at the `diff_smallest_startdate_drop_out` it calculates wrong for ID 5. The first entry is correct (39) but, e.g. the second should be the difference of 2015-04-11 and 2015-04-16.

Comment: i edited my code base on your comment :https://dbfiddle.uk/93Uz9uZJ